# React Axios error doesnt actually get resolved, it gets an error creating the error

Tags: reactjs, axios

Im building a react app with a spring boot server and when i log in with password right, it comes 200 all works, but when i miss the password on purpose to test what happens, Axios does't parse the error.

It says:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

and the actual error occurs here

```
export async function login(login: Credentials) {
    try {
        const result = await axios.put(base + 'user', login)
        return result
    } catch (err) {
        --> console.log(err)
        return err
    }
}
```

The error occurs in the console.log, telling me it detected it was not a code 200 therefore it blew up there but it cant actually resolve the error?
Im quite lost with this, ive use axios for ages and this never happened.
I ve also deployed the server to Azure to not put the server and website in the same machine cuz cors but nothing helped.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you returning the error in your catch? I'm also curious why you're using a PUT for a login function?

Comment: I was returning err.response to get the response of the error but it didnt work. I noticed the put and changed but even then it should work regardless of that no?

Comment: Did you try console.logging ```err.response```? Just logging err will print the error message and stack trace.

Comment: I did, i put console.log(err.response) and i return it, it still goes to the response part instead of the error in the "then" of the axios promise by response i mean onFullfilled, and error onRejected

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I made a silly mistake. In the request function i do return err.response instead of THROW err.response
Thats how it passes to be a rejected promise instead of fullfilled. Sorry.